# Can not add function Odata WebAPI controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, odata

I am trying to add a function to an OData controller that merely returns some data. I have followed a few examples and they seem to make use of a

```
productType.Collection
                .Function("Top10")
                .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Product>("Products");
```

Function function. I can't seem to find this anywhere in the OData libraries I have in my application. They indicate [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn750496(v=vs.118).aspx) that it should be in the `System.Web.OData.Builder` but it doesn't seem to be..

Anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "***Function***" only exists in ***WebAPI odata V4*** while V3 only has Action.

Can you resolve namespace `System.Web.OData.Builder`?

If not, you can install nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.2.0`

Comment: This makes sense. I cannot resolve that namespace but I do have that package installed though it does explicitly state v1-3 on the name of the package. Is there somewhere else I have to get v4 from other than nuget?

Comment: I got it. The package was 'Microsoft.AspNet.Odata' though. Thanks dude.

Comment: What is the problem with nuget? I don't know anywhere but nuget. You can download the package by nuget and copy the dlls inside the package.

Comment: So what is the difference between the Microsoft.AspNet.Odata library and the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Odata library?

Comment: @Brandon: Microsoft.AspNet.OData is for OData V4 while Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData is for OData v1-3